# Selecting a range of rows in a Pandas data frame based on criteria from multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to select and create a new data frame from a range of rows in a current DF based on two criteria in different columns. Below is an example from a larger DF with two columns. I'm interested in creating a new DF with the rows starting where column 0 equals BEGIN_GROUP and column 1 equals R down to END_GROUP R. I can't just narrow it down based on column 0 only because BEGIN_GROUP and END_GROUP repeat many times through the DF, the only thing unique is the value in the adjacent column (in this case R). Thanks in advance.

```
                    0               1
15           compressionType        xx                     
16           jpegProfileName        xx                      
17               BEGIN_GROUP        R                 
18                     ULLon        xx            
19                     ULLat        xx           
20                     ULHAE        xx                  
21                     URLon        xx           
22                     URLat        xx             
23                     URHAE        xx                
24                     LRLon        xx            
25                     LRLat        xx             
26                     LRHAE        xx                  
27                     LLLon        xx            
28                     LLLat        xx             
29                     LLHAE        xx                  
30              absCalFactor        xx            
31        effectiveBandwidth        xx           
32                  TDILevel        xx                      
33                 END_GROUP        R                       
34               BEGIN_GROUP        G                       
35                     ULLon        xx
```

Comment: Do these groups ever overlap, i.e. a new group starting before the previous one finished?

Comment: No they shouldn't. They just start one after the other with a new unique value in column 1

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the issue is? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic]. You could at the very least provide the data in a more convenient format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC

```
# boolean indexing where column 0 has begin_group OR end_group
# AND col 1 is equal to R and get the index
idx = df[((df['0'].str.contains('BEGIN_GROUP|END_GROUP')) & (df['1'] == 'R'))].index
# use .loc with the index range
df.loc[idx[0]:idx[1]]

                     0   1
17         BEGIN_GROUP   R
18               ULLon  xx
19               ULLat  xx
20               ULHAE  xx
21               URLon  xx
22               URLat  xx
23               URHAE  xx
24               LRLon  xx
25               LRLat  xx
26               LRHAE  xx
27               LLLon  xx
28               LLLat  xx
29               LLHAE  xx
30        absCalFactor  xx
31  effectiveBandwidth  xx
32            TDILevel  xx
33           END_GROUP   R
```

Answer (score 0):

Going to assume your dataframe is bigger and actually has a proper index. To simulate this in the example:

```py
df = df.reset_index()
```

Build two dictionaries, one with starting indexes and one with ending indexes:

```py
beginnings = df.loc[df['0'] == 'BEGIN_GROUP']['1'].to_dict()
endings = df.loc[df['0'] == 'END_GROUP']['1'].to_dict()
beginnings, endings
```

```py
({17: 'R', 34: 'G'}, {33: 'R'})
```

Now build the new dataframes based on these saved indexes:

```py
dfs = {}
for begin_idx, begin_label in beginnings.items():
    for end_idx, end_label in endings.items():
        if begin_label == end_label:
            dfs[begin_label] = df.iloc[begin_idx:end_idx+1]
```

Note this builds a dictionary which include your dataframes. You can call them by their unique label:

```py
dfs['R']
```

```
    index                   0   1
2      17         BEGIN_GROUP   R
3      18               ULLon  xx
4      19               ULLat  xx
5      20               ULHAE  xx
6      21               URLon  xx
7      22               URLat  xx
8      23               URHAE  xx
9      24               LRLon  xx
10     25               LRLat  xx
11     26               LRHAE  xx
12     27               LLLon  xx
13     28               LLLat  xx
14     29               LLHAE  xx
15     30        absCalFactor  xx
16     31  effectiveBandwidth  xx
17     32            TDILevel  xx
18     33           END_GROUP   R
```